# scipy ndimage has no attribute filter?

Tags: python

I installed ndimage with `sudo pip3 install scipy`

then i'm importing it as `import scipy.ndimage`

then i'm doing the following line `b=scipy.ndimage.filter.gaussian_filter(i,sigma=10)`

and I get `AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'filter'`
Anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
It should have been `b=scipy.ndimage.filters` instead of filter

Answer (score 0):

For python3, it can be used like below, no need to add scipy.

```
from scipy.ndimage import filters
my_image2 = filters.gaussian_filter(my_image,10)
```

Comment: It says the following now: `scipy.ndimage.filters is deprecated and has no attribute gaussian. Try looking in scipy.ndimage instead.`